# TouchScreen GUI Reference Guide Help

Tags: lcd, display, tft

Recently I have gotten some Touchscreens to add to my projects and I am very excited to use them. However, I am not sure where I can find a guide to help me create my own GUI with the touchscreens. The touchscreen I am using right now is the HiLetgo 2.4 inch TFT LCD Display Shield with a ILI9341 Driver. I have experience programming GUI's in Python and I feel fairly confident in myself that I can create the GUI's that I want if I had a resource to learn from. Please Let me know if you'd like anymore information. Thank you!

Comment: In general there's very little "GUI" programming functionality in TFT libraries. You have low-level operations mostly - things like line drawing. Making a GUI is a lot of programming.

Comment: Of course, it depends what library you are using as to what functionality you have...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am nit trying to make a super complex GUI but just one that's my own. I am using the Adafruit_GFX_Library. Are there better libraries out there or is the Adafruit library okay?

Comment: You get buttons and canvases as the only "objects" you can work with. Very basic. Anything more than that you have to draw yourself.